# PyQt Python: не запускаются UnitTest'ы

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, юнит-тесты, pyqt

Написала меню на PyQt, хочу протестировать один из методов внутри класса

`class MyClass(Qt.Widgets.QMainWindow, layout.mylayout)`

Оригинальный код тут: [тест](https://gitlab.com/adtsvetkov/lab2/-/blob/develop/src/test.py), [тестируемый код](https://gitlab.com/adtsvetkov/lab2/-/blob/develop/src/goui.py).

Код юниттестов выглядит примерно так:

```
class TestForMyMethod(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_name1(self):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    uc = MyClass()
    result = uc.test_method(1)
    app.exit()
    assert result < 1

  def test_name2(self):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    uc = MyClass()
    result = uc.test_method(2)
    app.exit()
    assert result < 1
```

Отдельно каждый тест проходится, ошибок не возникает. Однако если запустить все тесты сразу из класса `TestForMyMethod` проходится только один тест, остальные падают.
В чем может быть проблема? В ивент логе такое:

```
    Failed to start: 1, passed: 1
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: добавила ссылки на оригинальный код